# what does "attend the services " mean to you?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, translation

Consider the following English sentence which I've translated from "他去会堂守礼拜了。" :

> He went to attend the services in the synagogue.

What does "attend the services" mean to you?

Comment: Sure you can. That's how I translate it. Of course, I know no Chinese, so I translate all Chinese as "*attend the services*".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about translating Chinese to English.

Comment: oh, i am sorry about that. i just want to know what's the meaning of "attend the services" to you to see whether people can get the right meaning if i translate it like this. you can ignore the Chinese sentence, of course.

Comment: A "service" in a synagogue would be an occasion where many people come together there for a religious observance.

Comment: After your edit, I would, if I could, change my reason for voting to close to this: The question is off-topic because it doesn't show research - trying to find the answer yourself. Have you consulted a dictionary for the meanings of "attend" and "services"? If so, what about those definitions and the resulting phrase is unclear to you?

Comment: Just be careful, *attendING the services* means you're going to a funeral, which this sounds awfully close to. Try no `s` and no `the`: *attend service.* (Also, I think *in* should be *at*, but I'm unsure: *went to attend service at*)

Comment: @Mazura "attend service" is borderline incorrect in American English, while "attending the services" does not imply in any way that you are going to a funeral.

Comment: so, you can't understand the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: A "service" in some sort of church-like institution is a religious ceremony of some sort, at least in the US.

Comment: @Mazura - You are being a bit too prescriptive.  I could be "attending the service" for Christmas and it would not imply a funeral.  In fact, only if one says "attending the service for John Smith" would I assume it is a funeral (or "memorial service").

Comment: ok, thank you very much. so it can convey the meaning.